Issue with Sequential Animation of Text in Hover Effect
I have a text animation where I want the original text to move upwards and reveal a new text when hovered over. However, the sequential animation of the secondary text (nav-hidden-text) does not work properly on the first hover. It works fine on subsequent hovers and leaves, but the initial hover does not trigger the sequence as expected.


document.querySelectorAll('.nav-container').forEach(container => {
    let isHovering = false;
    let timeoutId = null;

    function updateTransitionDelays() {
        container.querySelectorAll('.nav-text .letter').forEach((letter, index) => {
            letter.style.transitionDelay = `${index * 0.05}s`;
        });
        container.querySelectorAll('.nav-hidden-text .letter').forEach((letter, index) => {
            letter.style.transitionDelay = `${(index * 0.05) + 0.2}s`;
        });
    }

    function forceReflow() {
        container.offsetHeight; // Forces a reflow to ensure animation starts
    }

    container.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        isHovering = true;
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);

        // Force reflow
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            container.classList.add('hover');
            container.classList.remove('leave');
            updateTransitionDelays();
            forceReflow(); // Forces reflow to update styles
        });
    });

    container.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        isHovering = false;

        // Force reflow
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            updateTransitionDelays();
            timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                if (!isHovering) {
                    container.classList.add('leave');
                    container.classList.remove('hover');
                }
            }, 50); // Adjust time as needed
        });
    });
});
.nav-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-text, .nav-hidden-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.4s ease;
}

.nav-text {
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav-hidden-text {
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: top 0.4s ease; /* Ensure this is set */
}

.letter {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.nav-container.hover .nav-text .letter {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
}

.nav-container.hover .nav-hidden-text {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav-container.hover .nav-hidden-text .letter {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav-container.leave .nav-text .letter {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav-container.leave .nav-hidden-text {
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.nav-container.leave .nav-hidden-text .letter {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
}
<div class="nav-container">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <div class="nav-text">
            <span class="letter">O</span>
            <span class="letter">r</span>
            <span class="letter">i</span>
            <span class="letter">g</span>
            <span class="letter">i</span>
            <span class="letter">n</span>
            <span class="letter">a</span>
            <span class="letter">l</span>
            <span class="letter"> </span>
            <span class="letter">T</span>
            <span class="letter">e</span>
            <span class="letter">k</span>
            <span class="letter">s</span>
            <span class="letter">t</span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-hidden-text">
            <span class="letter">N</span>
            <span class="letter">y</span>
            <span class="letter"> </span>
            <span class="letter">T</span>
            <span class="letter">e</span>
            <span class="letter">k</span>
            <span class="letter">s</span>
            <span class="letter">t</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>



The sequential animation of nav-hidden-text does not work correctly on the first hover. On subsequent hovers and leaves, the animation behaves as expected. The nav-text moves up and nav-hidden-text takes its place. When the mouse is not hovering, nav-hidden-text moves down, and nav-text returns to its original position.
What I've Tried:
Ensured that transition and animation properties are correctly applied.
Used JavaScript to force reflow and update transition delays.
Verified that transitions and animations are properly set in CSS.

I found cause of issue at first glance but finding solution was tricky as js integration was a bit hard to understand. First of your animation looks so good, now lets understand cause of issue.
The animation was working best after first hover because after first hover all css properties were applied to make animation good. This two properties were missing at start transition-delay: 0.2s & transform: translateY(100%) on second text.
This is what you need to do for fixing issue :

Add above mentioned css properties to second text.
Add transform: translateY(0) !important; to .nav-container.hover .nav-hidden-text .letter, so that it overrides style on second text when hover class is added.

Thats all, below is working example with code and this is codepen link. If this fixes your issue then accept it as answer so it can help people with similar issue.


document.querySelectorAll('.nav-container').forEach(container => {
    let isHovering = false;
    let timeoutId = null;

    function updateTransitionDelays() {
        container.querySelectorAll('.nav-text .letter').forEach((letter, index) => {
            letter.style.transitionDelay = `${index * 0.05}s`;
        });
        container.querySelectorAll('.nav-hidden-text .letter').forEach((letter, index) => {
            letter.style.transitionDelay = `${(index * 0.05) + 0.2}s`;
        });
    }

    function forceReflow() {
        container.offsetHeight; // Forces a reflow to ensure animation starts
    }

    container.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        isHovering = true;
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);

        // Force reflow
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            container.classList.add('hover');
            container.classList.remove('leave');
            updateTransitionDelays();
            forceReflow(); // Forces reflow to update styles
        });
    });

    container.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        isHovering = false;

        // Force reflow
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            updateTransitionDelays();
            timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                if (!isHovering) {
                    container.classList.add('leave');
                    container.classList.remove('hover');
                }
            }, 50); // Adjust time as needed
        });
    });
});
.nav-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-text, .nav-hidden-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.4s ease;
}

.nav-text {
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav-hidden-text {
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: top 0.4s ease; /* Ensure this is set */
/*     transform: translateY(100%); */
}

.letter {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.letter2 {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease, opacity 0.4s ease;
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.nav-container.hover .nav-text .letter {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
}

.nav-container.hover .nav-hidden-text {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav-container.hover .nav-hidden-text .letter {
    transform: translateY(0) !important;
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav-container.leave .nav-text .letter {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav-container.leave .nav-hidden-text {
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.nav-container.leave .nav-hidden-text .letter {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
}

.nav-container.leave .nav-hidden-text .letter {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
}
<div class="nav-container">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <div class="nav-text">
            <span class="letter">O</span>
            <span class="letter">r</span>
            <span class="letter">i</span>
            <span class="letter">g</span>
            <span class="letter">i</span>
            <span class="letter">n</span>
            <span class="letter">a</span>
            <span class="letter">l</span>
            <span class="letter"> </span>
            <span class="letter">T</span>
            <span class="letter">e</span>
            <span class="letter">k</span>
            <span class="letter">s</span>
            <span class="letter">t</span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-hidden-text">
            <span class="letter" style="transition-delay: 0.2s;transform: translateY(100%);">N</span>
            <span class="letter" style="transition-delay: 0.25s;transform: translateY(100%);">y</span>
            <span class="letter" style="transition-delay: 0.3s;transform: translateY(100%);"> </span>
            <span class="letter" style="transition-delay: 0.35s;transform: translateY(100%);">T</span>
            <span class="letter" style="transition-delay: 0.4s;transform: translateY(100%);">e</span>
            <span class="letter" style="transition-delay: 0.45s;transform: translateY(100%);">k</span>
            <span class="letter" style="transition-delay: 0.5s;transform: translateY(100%);">s</span>
            <span class="letter" style="transition-delay: 0.55s;transform: translateY(100%);">t</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>




Fantastic, thank you very much. This solved the issue perfectly.
